# Set initial value with django-filters?

Tags: python, django, django-filters

When using the [django-filters](https://django-filter.readthedocs.org) app, how can I set the initial value of the field in my filter?

Usually with a standard form in `Django`, for example a simple selection list form:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    OPTIONS=(('APP','Apple'),('BAN','Banana')) 
    country = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(),
                                         choices=OPTIONS, initial='BAN')
```

to initialise the forms entry to `Banana`. However, in my `filter.py` if I have something like:

```
class MyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    OPTIONS=(('APP','Apple'),('BAN','Banana')) 
    myfield = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(
             widget=django_filters.widgets.forms.Select(),choices=OPTIONS)
    .
    .
```

where do I put the `initial='BAN'` to get the initially selected element of the dropdown etc?
I tried the `ChoiceFilter` arguments and `Select()` arguments to no avail.

I thought the idea of `Filters` was to mirror very closely the behaviour of `Forms` only with the added benefit of filtering obviously, so I'm surprised initialising in (to what seems to me) the intuitive place does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the other answers I would do it by not changing the data from the `request.GET`, but modifying directly the queryset:

```
def get_filterset_kwargs(self, filterset_class):
    kwargs = super().get_filterset_kwargs(filterset_class)
    if kwargs['data'] is None:
        kwargs['queryset'] = kwargs['queryset'].filter(myfield ='BAN')
    return kwargs
```

I use this approach because by changing the `kwargs['data']`
 from `request.GET` to a `dict`, you loose the `getlist` method and can just retrieve one value per key.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.   It sets a default if no data is provided in the request:

```
data = request.GET.copy()
if len(data) == 0:
    data['field'] = initial_value
filters = MyFilterSet(data)
```

Comment: Where should you place this code?

Answer (score 1):

Using the same approach as user1867622, I use:

```
get_query = request.GET.copy()
if 'status' not in get_query:
    get_query['status'] = 'final'
sfilter = MatterFilterSet(get_query, queryset=matters)
```