# Initial value is not working for ChoiceField on django-filters

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I've the following django-filter (https://github.com/alex/django-filter/) filter:

```
class ApplicationFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    status = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=STATUS2,)
```

with status containing the following tuple list:

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ( '', u'All'),
    ( 'NEW', u'New'),
    ( 'SUBMIT', u'Submit'),
    ( 'CANCEL', u'Cancel'),
)
```

Now, I'd like to set an initial value for that filter different than the empty one (All). So I tried the following things, all *without* success:

i. Adding an initial parameter to the field:
`status = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=STATUS2, initial = 'NEW' )` or with an array `status = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices=STATUS2, initial = ['NEW'] )`. The form rendered with the default initial value.

ii. Modifying the `__init__` of the form:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ApplicationFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form.initial['status']='NEW'
        self.form.fields['status'].initial='NEW'
```

-- again the form rendered with the default initial value (All)... Also tried setting the value as `['NEW']` -- again no luck.

Does anybody know how should this be handled ? I am using the latest (from github) version of django-filter.

TIA

Comment: Try to call parent method `__init__` after set initial values.

Comment: Should I call it *again* ? I already call it once !

Comment: No, no again. Just move this `super(...)` line to the end. I never had a problem with that. I looked into one of my project and I call it at the end. I'm not sure if it's a solution for your problem.

Comment: ``self.form`` is throwing an exception if I put it after the super line *after*. I did just a ``print self.form`` before ``super()`` and got: ``AttributeError: 'ApplicationFilter' object has no attribute 'filters'``

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ApplicationFilter, self).init(*args, **kwargs)
    self.initial['status'] = 'NEW'
```

Comment: Hello @Alejandro - as you'll see from my anser I've already tried ``self.form.initial['status']='NEW'`` with no luck :(

Comment: @fierroformo that does not work either. Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This answer might work for you:
[Set initial value with django-filters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21840365/set-initial-value-with-django-filters/42806241#42806241)

In my views, I do:

```
get_query = request.GET.copy()
if 'status' not in get_query:
    get_query['status'] = 'final'
filter_set = MatterFilterSet(get_query)
```